# Worker interrupting main program in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, interrupt

So basically what I want to do is have my main program to do some calculations, unrelated to a parallel program. The parallel program is constantly checking for some event to come true, and when it does, I want the main program to freeze and start another parallel job. Is it possible to do so in Matlab? 
You can imagine it as a robot riding (main program) and at the same time checking its sensor data (worker). When it approaches an obstacle, a program to avoid the obstacle is started.
Thanks in advance, 
Rugile :)

Comment: What have you attempted to complete this task? What worked about it what didn't?

Comment: Your use of main and parallel is a bit confusing. Do I understand this correctly? At the beginning you want function `A` and `B` to run, then once a condition is met in `A` you want `B` to pause and you want to start function `C`? Also what do your programs look like? Are they all in a big loop or in sequential blocks? Perhaps you could check for a stop condition somewhere in the loop or between the blocks. -- If you want to freeze a program, you will probably have to let that program check whether it needs to freeze as I doubt it can be done from outside.

Comment: Well the program is a big loop. I guess the timer solution will do just ok :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution to this that I have seen is to use a Matlab timer object.

Implementation code would look something like this:

```
%Setup timer
t = timer;
t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedSpacing';  %See `docsearch Timer Object Execution Modes` for explaination
t.Period = 1;  %Number of seconds after one execution to the start of the next
t.TimerFcn = @checkAndExecuteParallelJob
start(t);

%Start main job
mainJob();
```

In another file

```
function checkAndExecuteParallelJob
if (conditionIsFalse)
    %Fast return
    return;
end
%..Code to execute parallel job.  This will block the main execution
```

Matlab is not multi-threaded, so the execution of a timer callback function will interrupt and block the execution of any main function.  Timers can also interrupt each other, sometimes but not always, with a complex set of rules that I once tried to reverse engineer but have since given up on.  However, for the relatively simple problem you laid out, I think that a timer object would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to do :)